# To solve an exception details in web site creation

Tags: c#

I am creating a web site but anytime I run this code, an exception is raised:

```
#Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 0.
```

How do I solve this problem?

```
public partial class Employee_frmSearchClaims : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int empno;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["empno"] != null)
            empno = int.Parse(Session["empno"].ToString());

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         DataRow r = AddPoliciesOnEmployees.GetPolicyOnEmployee(empno).Tables[0].Rows[0];
                Label7.Text = r["policyname"].ToString();
                Label8.Text = r["policyid"].ToString();
                Label9.Text = r["policyamount"].ToString();
                Label10.Text = r["TotalAmount"].ToString();
                Label11.Text = r["pstartdate"].ToString();
            }
        }

    protected void btnapplicy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlReason.SelectedItem.ToString() != "--Select--")
        {
            if (ddlReason.SelectedItem.Text == "Death")
            {
                Session["Reason"] = ddlReason.SelectedItem.Text;
                Response.Redirect("frmDeathCliam.aspx");
            }
            else if (ddlReason.SelectedItem.Text == "Accident")
            {
                Session["Reason"] = ddlReason.SelectedItem.Text;
                Response.Redirect("frmAccidentClaim.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Reason"] = ddlReason.SelectedItem.Text;
                Response.Redirect("frmCompleteClaim.aspx");
            }

        }
      else
            lblmsg.Text = "You have to select the reason";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you tell us in which line this error happens?

Comment: l think it's this place:    Line 22:    if (!IsPostBack)
                            Line 23:      {
 Line 24:DataRow r = AddPoliciesOnEmployees.GetPolicyOnEmployee(empno).Tables[0].Rows[0];
Line 25: Label7.Text = r["policyname"].ToString();
Line 26: Label8.Text = r["policyid"].ToString();

Comment: I just retagged this as C#, but I'm not sure this is correct. Please retag if it isn't.

Comment: Either the Tables or the Rows array is empty.

Comment: @Rik Considering the error specifies rows, I'm going to guess... rows.

Comment: @mydogisbox: good call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your table contains rows first:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["empno"] != null)
        empno = int.Parse(Session["empno"].ToString());

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var ds = AddPoliciesOnEmployees.GetPolicyOnEmployee(empno);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow r = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            Label7.Text = r["policyname"].ToString();
            Label8.Text = r["policyid"].ToString();
            Label9.Text = r["policyamount"].ToString();
            Label10.Text = r["TotalAmount"].ToString();
            Label11.Text = r["pstartdate"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **l really appreciate all your contributions.that part is now working well thanks**